# What is the difference between succession tax and inheritance tax?

Tags: taxes, inheritance

I read on https://www.offshore-protection.com/panama-private-interest-foundations-formation ([mirror](https://web.archive.org/web/20211008090634/https://www.offshore-protection.com/panama-private-interest-foundations-formation)) (emphasis is mine):

> Panama is a true '[tax haven](https://www.offshore-protection.com/offshore-glossary-terms/13-tax-haven)'. Panama Foundations offer the following tax advantages:
>
> - No tax reporting requirements
> - No income tax
> - No capital gains tax
> - No interest income tax
> - No sales tax
> - No tax to beneficiaries
> - No beneficiary transfer tax
> - No capital tax
> - No property tax (for non-Panamanian property)
> - No estate tax
> - No gift tax
> - **No inheritance tax**
> - No stamp tax
> - **No succession tax**
> - No inventory tax

What is  the difference between succession tax and inheritance tax?

Comment: I'd guess that it's similar to the difference between an "estate tax" vs "inheritance tax", i.e. who pays it: "Estate and inheritance taxes are taxes levied on the transfer of property at death. An estate tax is levied on the estate of the deceased while an inheritance tax is levied on the heirs of the deceased."

Comment: It may be a dated term. For example, the US State of Connecticut had a "succession tax" until 2005, after which it became "estate tax".